# How can I get Eclipse to show non-printable characters like IntelliJ does

Tags: eclipse

I deal with a lot of non-printable characters used as delimiters (\u001D) and IntelliJ will show them in Strings and in the console. Eclipse does not and I can't find a way to get it to show them.

IntelliJ is showing them as a little box that I can then copy and paste if need be.

Comment: share sceenshot here http://imgur.com

Answer (score 13):

Is that what are you looking for?

`Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors`

Look for `Show whitespace characters` and click on the link *([whitespace characters](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-texteditorprefs.htm))* (<= v3.6) or *([configure visibility](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-texteditorprefs.htm))* (>= v3.7).